# PHP - SQL Update and Replace issues

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Example of my Table which is called "accounts":

```
game          accounts
---------------------------------
minecraft_pc  test:123
cod           123:test
bla           blabla
```

When they buy an account using PayPal IPN and this query gets sent in the script:

```
query("UPDATE accounts SET accounts = REPLACE(accounts, :boughtaccount, '') WHERE game = :game","unfed_shop",array(":game"=>$_POST['item_name'],":boughtaccount"=>$accountquery));
```

For some reason it wont work I know for a fact the issue isnt with the custom query().

Full PHP:

```
//Prepare the Statements for the query;
if(strpos($st[0]['accounts'],',')) {
    $accountquery = $st2[0].', ';
} else {
    $accountquery = $st2[0];
}

//Remove the ready account from the database;
query("UPDATE accounts SET accounts = REPLACE(accounts, :boughtaccount, '') WHERE game = :game","unfed_shop",array(":game"=>$_POST['item_name'],":boughtaccount"=>$accountquery));
```

query() PHP:

```
function Connect($host = false,$username = false,$password = false,$dbname = false) {

    //Try execute the PHP with no errors;
    try {

        //Create a PDO Session;
        $con = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

        //Session Attributes;
        $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

    }

    //Catch all PDOException errors;
    catch (PDOException $e) {

        //Make the PDO session false;
        $con = false;

    }

    //If no errors happened Make the PDO session true;
    return $con;

}

function query($sql = false,$dbname = false,$bind = false,$obj = false) {

    //Prepare The SQL Query;
    $query = Connect('localhost','unfed_admin','pass',$dbname)->prepare($sql);

    $res = true;

    //Execute Binded Query;
    try { $query->execute($bind); $res = true; }

    catch (PDOException $e) {

        $res = false;

    }

    //If no errors happened Make $row true;
    return $res;

}
```

For some reason im not getting any errors. Any idea?

Comment: "I know for a fact the issue isnt with the custom query()" then you shouldn't mind including it so that we can also draw this conclusion?

Comment: Its definitely not @Sammitch because its working fine with other queries.

Comment: Why bother using `ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` if you're just going to catch the exception, return false, and then never actually check the return value or the exception? I suggest checking the return of your `query()` function at least, if not removing that useless try/catch and letting the Exception bubble up to where you can see it and know what went wrong.

Comment: @Sammitch Havent been coding for a few months how can I get it to output any errors again?

Comment: Update! I found out the issue is the $accountquery part where it checks to see if theres a , in the accounts column and if there is also remove ", ". I changed the query from ":boughtaccount"=>$accountquery to ":boughtaccount"=>$st2[0] and it removed the test:123 (Example) just fine BUT now how am I meant to get it to check if to remove just the account or the account + ", " as if I put it into a strpos checker like I used in my OP it wont work for some reason.